# Best batch practice to run a second command with &&

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

i'm looking for best practice in a situation where i want to send two commands to a separate window. as in:

```
start /wait command1 && command2
```

this works however the second command is not executed in the new window instead runs in the initial window after the first task is finished.

how should a situation like this be handled correct?

Comment: `start /wait command1 && command2` is parsed as `(start /wait command1) && command2` so the command2 is still run in the old cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it directly with `start` but `cmd` supports that using quotes:

```
start /wait cmd /c "command1 && command2"
```

You probably can use `cmd` directly:

```
cmd /c "command1 && command2"
```